# Different asp:menu on a user basis

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemapprovider, aspmenu

I have a oracle database which stores menu and user data, for a local Intranet.

The data includes which usesr have access to which pages.

Originally I created a class which extened the StaticSiteMapProvider class, however when this went in to the testing environment, i found that this was cached for the whole site (and not on a user basis).  After reading up on line on various forums, it was suggested that I should inherit from SiteMapProvider as this would enable me to have a seperated instance of thet SiteMapProvider and ASP:MENU item on a user basis, however this still hasn't solved the problem.

Currently I have a user control, which conrains the asp:menu, and uses my custom site map provider as its data source.

Could anyone suggest how I can display the menu on a user basis, driven from database authorisation?

Also the whole menu should still appear to all users, it only after thy click on a menu node that they will find out whether they have access to that page/node.

Thanks

Comment: want to create menus dynamically

Comment: @NDC: Yeah basically, however I am not using asp roles

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Roles on the SiteMap to define what menu will appear.

Comment: Thanks Davis, but the developer who wrote this code decided not to use roles, he has implemented his own page authorisation based on menu items and sitemapnodes

Comment: @jpgooner, override `IsAccessibleToUser` method - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here. If you have static collection of nodes and then you want to show/hide them based on user accessibility then you should override [IsAccessibleToUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapprovider.isaccessibletouser.aspx)
method to tell if the given node if applicable for the current user (accessible from given HttpContext).

In case, your nodes collection/hierarchy changes per user basis then try overriding [BuildSiteMap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.staticsitemapprovider.buildsitemap.aspx) to load different nodes for current user. However, I am a bit doubtful if StaticSiteMapProvider is the correct base class in this case. Probably you need to override from `SiteMapProvider`.

Comment: The custom site map provider class did originally override staticSiteMapProvider, but I have since changed it to overrider SiteMapProvider and still have no joy?, also I still want all nodes to appear....